# How to find the radius of gyration for a protein?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, structural-biology, protein-folding, protein-structure

While going through the paper titled "GEOMETRIC ANALYSIS OF THE CONFORMATIONAL FEATURES OF PROTEIN STRUCTURES" by Manish Dutt, it talked about finding the radius of gyration of each protein structure. I am unable to understand how the radius of gyration has been obtained for the entire protein. I first find the root mean square distance between the centroid and the C alpha atom. Is the average of these distances the radius of gyration?

Comment: Pretty sure that there are library methods to calculate this - otherwise the formula for the radius of gyration of a set of points is on wikipedia? in any case, more of a bioinformatics question than a biology one...

Comment: Radius of gyration (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_gyration) is a basic-physics concept. If we rotate freely a point-mass, we can quite easily derive various inter-related variables from other-such variables (like mass, speed, radius, etc); but if it is a complex object (say a wheel or stone), it is complicated, but we can imagin an EQUIVALENT point-mass in rotating; whose mass is same as whole object, and radius, speed, frequency-of rotation etc. all characteristics are exactly same to our object.

Comment: there are square-roots in derivations for radius of gyration, and they are looking like (root (a. b. c. d... (r^2))) pattern. But I can't tell whether it is r.m.s. of that distance, or not. (from my H.S school physics textbook)

Comment: @Rishika you could go-through the paper slowly, and mark statements and sketches which could be useful. Then add some more details to question. You could provide a link to the paper. Is it freely accessible paper?